# How can i get value from object in Array with Promise?

Tags: javascript

```html
[
  Promise {
    {
      filename: '5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
    }
  },
  Promise {
    {
      filename: '54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
    }
  }
]
```

i want to get filename value from this data like this;

```
{ 5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg, 54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**`SOLUTION 1`**

Since you have an array of promises then you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allhttps://)

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve({
    filename: '5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
});

const promise2 = Promise.resolve({
    filename: '54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
});

async function getFileNames() {
    const promiseArr = [promise1, promise2];
    const resultArr = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
    const result = resultArr.map((o) => o.filename);
    console.log(result);
}

getFileNames();
```

> NOTE: `Promise.all` also returns a promise and it will only be resolved if all of the promises are resolved. If any of the promise gets rejected in `Promise.all` then overall it will be rejected.

[`differences between Promise.all Promise.allsettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

**`SOLUTION 2`**

You can also use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) here. It will give you an array of objects and each object will contain two properties i.e `status` and `value`.

`status` can either be `fulfilled` or `rejected` and you can filter them all according to your requirement.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve({
    filename: '5A756579-9191-49D0-8B02-89B0A232FAA4_1_102_o.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
});

const promise2 = Promise.resolve({
    filename: '54DF4C9A-A7E3-4ABE-BC22-6E4C3C73236E.jpeg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
});

async function getFileNames() {
    const promiseArr = [promise1, promise2];
    const resultArr = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArr);
    const result = resultArr.filter(({ status, value }) =>
        status === 'fulfilled' ? value : false
    );
    console.log(result);
}

getFileNames();
```